AAP2 workflow - ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, gather_facts
I created a workflow for provisioning vm from a template on vCenter.
In this workflow I have a first node of type template job that redirects on a second node according to the response to a survey with the variable os_choice windows or linux.
The machine provisioning template works properly alone as a template but in the worflow I get one on the first node:
PLAY [Redirection by OS] *******************************************************
TASK [Run template job deploy windows vcenter] *********************************
skipping: [localhost]
TASK [Run template job deploy linux vcenter] ***********************************
ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, gather_facts
The error appears to be in '/runner/project/prov_wrkfl_deploy_rhel_vcenter.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
---
- name: Template deployment linux
  ^ here

Here are the playbooks contained in the worflow template job:
- name: Deploy RHEL machine from a template on vCenter
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Template deployment
      community.vmware.vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ lookup ('env', 'VMWARE_HOST') }}"
        username: "{{ lookup ('env', 'VMWARE_USER') }}"
        password: "{{ lookup ('env', 'VMWARE_PASSWORD') }}"
        validate_certs: false
        datacenter: "{{ inv_vcenter_datacenter }}"
        folder: "{{ inv_folder }}"
        template: "{{ survey_template_linux }}"
        name: "{{ survey_vcenter_vm_name }} "
        state: poweredon
        disk:
        - size_gb: "{{ survey_disk_size }}"
          type: thin
          datastore: "{{ inv_datastore }}"
        hardware:
          memory_mb: "{{ survey_memory_size }}"
          num_cpus: "{{ survey_cpu_num }}"
        networks:
        - name: Management_Network
          device_type: vmxnet3
          ip: "{{ survey_ipv4 }}"
          netmask: "{{ survey_netmask }}"
          gateway: "{{ survey_gateway }}"
          dns_servers:
            - "{{ inv_dns_server1 }}"
            - "{{ inv_dns_server2 }}"
          dns_suffix:
            - "{{ inv_dns_suffix1 }}"
            - "{{ inv_dns_suffix2 }}"
          start_connected: true       
        customization:
          autologon: true
          hostname: "{{ survey_vm_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: deploy_vm


Could you explain to me the reason or the right way to proceed in this context.
Thank you very much,
I tried in the first redirect node to use a role with include_role and include_task as in my previous message.
